# Read elements from a txt file that are separeted by a character

Tags: c++, file, getline, stringstream

I'am working on a program where there are first names, last names and a numbers on a file and i need to read that information into my program. My actual problem is that there is people who doesnt have a second name or second last name. To solve the issue I started trying to read from a file until a specific character is found, For example:

```
Robert, Ford Black,208   //Where Robert is the first name, and Ford Black are his two last names
George Richard, Bradford,508 //Where George Richard are both his first names, and Bradford is his only last 
                      name
```

I am saving this information in three separeted string, one that will store first and second name, first last and second last name and the third one for the numbers.

I'm trying to only use native libraries from c++.
I've been reading that getline(a,b,c) and IStringStream can actually solve my problem but I don't know how to correctly implement it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of using `std::getline` with a delimiter character to read out of the string stream.  See a simplified example (no error checking) below:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    std::string firstName, lastName;
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::getline(iss, firstName, ',');  // A comma delimits end-of-input
    iss >> std::ws;                     // Skip over any whitespace characters
    std::getline(iss, lastName);        // Read remaining line
    std::cout << "First Name: " << firstName << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Last Name: " << lastName << std::endl;
}
```

Note the line `iss >> std::ws;` using `std::ws` from `<iomanip>` is there to eat up extra whitespace characters (which appear after your comma, in your example).

I'm assuming the C++ line comments in the input are only an annotation for this question, and not part of the actual input.

Comment: Sorry paddy but I'm kinda new when it comes to file management. You are using getline to get from the start of the line to the first ',' that is sees, then from that ',' to the end of the line. Is that correct? Also I am trying to implement it in a demo code inside a while(getline(reader,line)) loop, where reader is my ifstream variable, but havent found success yet. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: That's correct.  Your while loop is essentially the same thing as my loop.  It just reads a line from somewhere.  Where exactly is not really the point.  Are you saying you don't understand how to adapt this to your program?

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. Thank you very much paddy, this actually fits like a glove for the problem that I had!

Comment: You're welcome.  I noticed you added more stuff to your question, and I'm sure you can see it's easy to extend this approach to keep reading more stuff out of the line without really adding code clutter.

Comment: Yes, I've been looking how to solve this kind of problem for a while on some forums but I've never seen the usage of getline from point A to point B as you did it. I added some more information to the question in case someone else is looking to solve a similar problem can find this post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile("files.txt");
    string fullname;
    while(getline(myfile,fullname,'/')) break; //here im reading till the first / is acquired and the entire string is stored in "fullname"
    string firstname,lastname;
    size_t pos=fullname.find(',');
    firstname=fullname.substr(0,pos); //store the firstname
    lastname=fullname.substr(pos+1);// storee the lastname
    cout<<firstname<<" "<<lastname;

}
```

As the question posed was to read names im assuming before the digit if there were a " / " you can read upto the first occurance of /. this will give you the fullname. Then using the substr on the fullname and find the occurance of a comma if at all it exists. All the characters to the left of position of comma will form your first name and the rest on the right of the position of comma will form the lastname.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person who's asking now. Consider editing your answer to add an explanation and/or some more insight on why your solution is better than other ones. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As the question posed was to read names which is clearly followed by " // " you can read upto the first occurance of /. this will give you the fullname. Then using the substr on the fullname and find the occurance of a comma if at all it exists. All the characters to the left of position of comma will form your first name and the rest on the right of the position of comma will form the lastname.